# MediaElement.js Not Loading Subtitles

Tags: html5-video, mediaelement.js, subtitle

I'm trying to use MediaElement.js for an embedded player with subtitles, but it just says "English (loading)" and doesn't actually show the subtitles.

I'm using the [pre-made track demo](http://www.flcbranson.org/johndyer-mediaelement-2.9.5-32-g98263df/demo/mediaelementplayer-track.html) and it doesn't even work.

I created [another page](http://www.flcbranson.org/mediaelementjs.html) that uses the code from the MediaElement.js home page and it doesn't work, either.

Interestingly enough, the MediaElement.js [track demo page](http://www.mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=translation) DOES show the English subtitles, correctly, but DOES NOT do the translation that the code says it should.

Does my web server need a mime-type set for .srt and .vtt?  The documentation doesn't say anything about it (video mime-types are mentioned).

Comment: The page must be uploaded to a web server. Does the console shows any errors?

Answer (score 1):

It's [mentioned here](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/250) that jQuery version might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem recently and found out that this occurs when one forgets to set the `srclang` property on the `track` node..

Make sure to add it (in this case: dutch subtitling):

```
<track id="subtitles" kind="subtitles" label="Ondertitels" src="mysubs.srt" srclang="nl"></track>
```